# How to get a Firefox extetnion to wait for get request for the page contents?

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, get-request

my JavaScript grabs HTML dom elements from the page, but the page has to make an HTML get request to get he HTML
contents. how to i make my script run on the received HTML rather than the default.

```
const item1 = document.get
const item2 = document.get

console.log(item1)
console.log(item2)
```